# How to search a JSON hash using a Regex?

Tags: json, regex, ruby

I'm using an API to return all Macros to me, I am trying to return all the "macros" where "actions" contains a "value" matching my Regexp Pattern which I will link below.

I've tried below and other methods, but it returns me nil for present values. Any tips appreciated

```
macros["value"].select { |m| m['key'] == 'value' }.first['/^DE([0-9a-zA-Z]\s?){20}$/gm']
```

API result snippet:

```
   jsObj
=> {"macros"=>
  [{"url"=>"https://s/1900002708354.json",
    "id"=>1900002708354,
    "title"=>"Append Signature",
    "active"=>true,
    "updated_at"=>"2021-10-22T14:11:15Z",
    "created_at"=>"2021-10-22T14:11:15Z",
    "position"=>10001,
    "description"=>"This macro appends a signature to the message ",
    "actions"=>[{"field"=>"comment_value_html", "value"=>"<p>Mit besten Grüßen,</p><p>{{current_user.name}} [{{ticket.account}}]&nbsp; <br></p><p><br></p><p>{{dc.signature_email}}<br></p><p><br></p>"}],
    "restriction"=>nil},
   {"url"=>"949.json",
    "id"=>59071949,
    "title"=>"information",
    "description"=>nil,
    "actions"=>[{"field"=>"priority", "value"=>"low"}, {"field"=>"comment_value", "value"=>"DE89370400440532013000" "DE89 3704

 0044 0532 0130 00"
"}],
        "restriction"=>nil},
```

Desired Result:

```
  {
        "macros": [
            {
                "url": "x.json",
                "id": 1900002708354,
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "field": "comment_value_html",
                        "value": "DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00"
                    }
                ],
                "restriction": null
            },
 
              {
                "url": "x.json",
                "id": 59071949,
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "field": "priority",
                        "value": "low"
                    },
                    {
                        "field": "comment_value",
                        "value": "DE89 3704 0044 0532 0130 00
"
                    }
                ],
                "restriction": null
            },
```

Comment: Whenever you give an example please show the desired result, here as a valid Ruby object (e.g., an array or hash). Note that `"IBANS"` does not appear in the JSON (only `"IBAN"`). What do you mean by "Macro"?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the tip, I've updated w/ desired result. A Macro in this case in a text template of sorts, as seen in the API response above, above I have a snippet containing 3 macros.

Comment: It is still a bit unclear. Maybe all you need is to get the `macros` where `actions` contains a 
 `value` matching your pattern? See https://ideone.com/JWT8Xr

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for, I'll update to make it more clear, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `macros` is the JSON object containing the `macros` data, you can use

```rb
macros.select { |m| m["actions"].any? { |w| /\ADE(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]\s?){20}\z/.match?(w["value"]) } }
```

Here is a Ruby demo:

```
require 'json'

j = <<-DATA
{
    "macros": [
        {
            "url": "x.json",
            "id": 1900002708354,
            "actions": [
                {
                    "field": "comment_value_html",
                    "value": "DE11111111111222222220"
                }
            ],
            "restriction": null
        },
        {
            "url": "x.json",
            "id": 59071949,
            "actions": [
                {
                    "field": "priority",
                    "value": "low"
                },
                {
                    "field": "comment_value",
                    "value": "DE12345678901234567890"
                }
            ],
            "restriction": null
        }
]}
DATA

jsObj = JSON.parse(j)
macros = jsObj['macros']
puts jsObj['macros'].select { |m| m["actions"].any? { |w| /\ADE(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]\s?){20}\z/.match?(w["value"]) } }
```

Output:

```
{"url"=>"x.json", "id"=>1900002708354, "actions"=>[{"field"=>"comment_value_html", "value"=>"DE11111111111222222220"}], "restriction"=>nil}
{"url"=>"x.json", "id"=>59071949, "actions"=>[{"field"=>"priority", "value"=>"low"}, {"field"=>"comment_value", "value"=>"DE12345678901234567890"}], "restriction"=>nil}
```

The `.select { |m| m["actions"].any? { |w| /\ADE(?:[0-9a-zA-Z]\s?){20}\z/.match?(w["value"]) } }` main part gets all `actions` nodes that contain an array with a `value` key whose value matches the regex given.

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, despite it working with your given link, it is returning empty arrays for me. It seems to be unable to reach the value key, as no Regexp returns a non empty result.

Comment: value is referred to as a NilClass

Comment: @cdln That means you have not provided the JSON you have.

Comment: Strange, I took the printed result from Postman. I have updated the snippet with the value of jsobj, which should be accurate.

Comment: @cdln Do you want to say your regex is not matching what it should? I understand your problem was applying it on the JSON. If the `value` field can *contain* the pattern, replace `\A` and `\z`  in the pattern with `\b`.

Comment: that's exactly it. I will try to make my questions more concise + clear as to the issue going forward, thanks for the help.